# c# listbox In ASP.Net

Tags: c#

How can i check whether item S (already in listbox1) exists in listbox2?
I used following code but it shows :

> The best overloaded method match for 
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Contains(System.Web.UI.WebControl
>   s.ListItem)' has some invalid arguments

Here is my code :

```
foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
{
    string s = i.Text;
    Response.Write(s);

    if ((ListBox2.Items.Contains(s) == true))
    {
        Response.Write("Already");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        l1.Text += "<li>" + i.Text;
        ListBox2.Items.Add(i.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Item` is a listitem and not a `string` and thus you should pass the listitem instead like

```
foreach (ListItem i in ListBox1.Items)
{
    string s = i.Text;
    Response.Write(s);

    if ((ListBox2.Items.Contains(i) == true))
```